# Typescript React alias HOC (to use <Component.alias />) typing issues

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to create a HOC (which I also want to be able to use as a decorator) to do the following:

Assume I have a component called "counter"

```
interface ICounterProps {
  count: number;
}

interface ICounter<T> extends React.Component<T> {
  // I'd have to add all aliases here manually I guess
  startAt5?: React.SFC<ICounterProps>
}

class Counter extends React.Component<ICounterProps> implements ICounter<ICounterProps> {
  render() {
    return <div>{this.props.count}</div>
  }
}
```

Now my HOC should do something like:

```
const alias = (name: string, setProps: {}) => (Component: any) => {
  Component[name] = (props: {}) => <Component {...setProps} {...props} />
}
```

So I can use it as a decorator for class components or as a function for functional components:

```
@alias('startAt5', { count: 5 })
class counter {...}

interface IOtherCounterProps {
  otherCount: number;
}

interface IOtherCounter extends React.SFC<IOtherCounterProps> {
  startAt10?: React.SFC<IOtherCounterProps>
}

const someOtherCounter: IOtherCounter = ({}) => {...}
alias('startAt10', { otherCount: 10 })(SomeOtherCounter);
```

And later use my component with different presets like:

```
<Counter.startAt5 />
<OtherCounter.startAt10 />
```

The code should work like this (or is working like this), made this sandbox so you can try it out:
https://codesandbox.io/s/ww1vrqlxw7

Though inside the index.tsx you see TS warnings on the components created by alias. And also alias isn't really typed properly.

So my questions:

1. Which types can you use to type `Component` and `props` properly?
2. Can you even type `setProps` (to use ICounterProps when used as decorator on Counter)?
3. Can you dynamically generate `ICounter` or `IOtherCounter` to include all aliases?
4. Can you shorten the `class Counter` type somehow (to only use one extend or implement)?
5. Is there maybe even a much better solution to create pre-propped subcomponents?

Kind regards.

Comment: An interesting question, not sure why you got the downvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this 'pre-propped subcomponents' is the react way to achive this, but typescript can help with points 1-4.

You can achieve an effect you want with no extra typing on usage. The trick is that we pass the original component to a function and use the return value of the function which will mutate the original type to have the extra sub components correctly typed:

```
// Helper type to extarct the props form a component type
type ComponentProps<T extends React.ComponentClass<any> | React.SFC<any>> = 
    T extends React.ComponentClass<infer P> ? P :
    T extends React.SFC<infer P> ? P : never;


type RestOfProperties<TAllProps, TPartial extends Partial<TAllProps>> =
    Pick<TAllProps, Exclude<keyof TAllProps, keyof TPartial>> & Partial<TPartial>;

// We need to declare 2 versions of the function that does the mutating of the type one for SCF the other for ComponentClass
// There may be a solution with a single class but I can't see it right now
    declare class Helper<TComponent extends React.ComponentClass<any>, TAllProps extends ComponentProps<TComponent>> {
    Component: TComponent;
    alias<TName extends string, TProps extends Partial<ComponentProps<TComponent>> & Record<Exclude<keyof TProps, keyof ComponentProps<TComponent>>, never> >(name: TName, setProps: TProps) : 
        Helper<TComponent & { [P in TName]: (props: RestOfProperties<TAllProps, TProps>) => JSX.Element }, TAllProps>
}
declare class HelperSCF<TComponent extends React.SFC<any>, TAllProps extends ComponentProps<TComponent>> {
    Component: TComponent;
    alias<TName extends string, TProps extends Partial<ComponentProps<TComponent>> & Record<Exclude<keyof TProps, keyof ComponentProps<TComponent>>, never>>(name: TName, setProps: TProps) : 
        HelperSCF<TComponent & { [P in TName]: (props: RestOfProperties<TAllProps, TProps>) => JSX.Element }, TAllProps>
}
// Define the aliasFactory function, with overlaods for SCF and ComponentClass
function aliasFactory<TComponent extends React.SFC<any>>(Component: TComponent) : HelperSCF<TComponent, ComponentProps<TComponent>>
function aliasFactory<TComponent extends React.ComponentClass<any>>(Component: TComponent) : Helper<TComponent, ComponentProps<TComponent>> 
function aliasFactory<TComponent extends React.ComponentClass<any> | React.SFC<any>>(Component: TComponent) {
    class Helper<T extends React.SFC<any>> {
        public constructor(public Component: T) { }
        alias<TName extends string, TProps extends Partial<ComponentProps<TComponent>>>(name: TName, setProps: TProps) : any {
            (this.Component as any)[name] = (props: {}) => <this.Component {...setProps} {...props} />
            return this;
        }
    }

    return new Helper(Component as any);
};


// Usage sample 
// Have a mix of required and optional properties 
interface IOtherCounterProps {
    otherCount: number;
    speed?: number;
    required: number;
}

// Define the implementation 
const OtherCounterImpl : React.SFC<IOtherCounterProps> = ({ otherCount }) => <div>{otherCount}</div>;

// This is the symbol we can export that will contain all our aliasses
const OtherCounter = aliasFactory(OtherCounterImpl)
    .alias("startAt10", { otherCount: 10 })
    .Component;


interface ICounterProps {
    count: number;
}

class CounterProto extends React.Component<ICounterProps> {
    render() {
        return <div>{this.props.count}</div>;
    }
}

// Similar for classes, we can add as may aliasses as we wish 
// This is the symbol we can export that will contain all our aliasses
const Counter = aliasFactory(CounterProto)
    .alias("startAt5", { count: 5})
    .alias("startAt10", { count: 10})
    // .alias("startAt10", { count: 10, notThere: ""}) // this would be an error (added after feedback)
    .Component;




let d = <div >
    <Counter count={3} />
    {/* Required properties that have been specified become optional  */}
    <Counter.startAt5  />
    <Counter.startAt10  />
    {/* Optional properties remnain optional, the required ones remain required */}
    <OtherCounter.startAt10 required={10}  />
</div>
```

Partial playground [link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=namespace%20React%20%7B%0D%0A%09export%20type%20SFC%3CP%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3E%20%3D%20StatelessComponent%3CP%3E%3B%0D%0A%09export%20interface%20StatelessComponent%3CP%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09(props%3A%20P%2C%20context%3F%3A%20any)%3A%20any%20%7C%20null%3B%0D%0A%09%09defaultProps%3F%3A%20Partial%3CP%3E%3B%0D%0A%09%09displayName%3F%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%09export%20interface%20ComponentClass%3CP%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09new(props%3A%20P%2C%20context%3F%3A%20any)%3A%20Component%3CP%2C%20any%3E%3B%0D%0A%09%09defaultProps%3F%3A%20Partial%3CP%3E%3B%0D%0A%09%09displayName%3F%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%09export%20interface%20Component%3CP%20%3D%20%7B%7D%2C%20S%20%3D%20%7B%7D%2C%20SS%20%3D%20never%3E%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%09export%20declare%20class%20Component%3CP%2C%20S%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09constructor(props%3A%20P%2C%20context%3F%3A%20any)%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Anamespace%20JSX%20%7B%0D%0A%09export%20interface%20Element%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Helper%20type%20to%20extarct%20the%20props%20form%20a%20component%20type%0D%0Atype%20ComponentProps%3CT%20extends%20React.ComponentClass%3Cany%3E%20%7C%20React.SFC%3Cany%3E%3E%20%3D%0D%0A%09T%20extends%20React.ComponentClass%3Cinfer%20P%3E%20%3F%20P%20%3A%0D%0A%09T%20extends%20React.SFC%3Cinfer%20P%3E%20%3F%20P%20%3A%20never%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20RestOfProperties%3CTAllProps%2C%20TPartial%20extends%20Partial%3CTAllProps%3E%3E%20%3D%0D%0A%09Pick%3CTAllProps%2C%20Exclude%3Ckeyof%20TAllProps%2C%20keyof%20TPartial%3E%3E%20%26%20Partial%3CTPartial%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20We%20need%20to%20declare%202%20versions%20of%20the%20function%20that%20does%20the%20mutating%20of%20the%20type%20one%20for%20SCF%20the%20other%20for%20ComponentClass%0D%0A%2F%2F%20There%20may%20be%20a%20solution%20with%20a%20single%20class%20but%20I%20can't%20see%20it%20right%20now%0D%0Adeclare%20class%20Helper%3CTComponent%20extends%20React.ComponentClass%3Cany%3E%2C%20TAllProps%20extends%20ComponentProps%3CTComponent%3E%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%09Component%3A%20TComponent%3B%0D%0A%09alias%3CTName%20extends%20string%2C%20TProps%20extends%20Partial%3CComponentProps%3CTComponent%3E%3E%3E(name%3A%20TName%2C%20setProps%3A%20TProps)%3A%0D%0A%09%09Helper%3CTComponent%20%26%20%7B%20%5BP%20in%20TName%5D%3A%20(props%3A%20RestOfProperties%3CTAllProps%2C%20TProps%3E)%20%3D%3E%20JSX.Element%20%7D%2C%20TAllProps%3E%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Adeclare%20class%20HelperSCF%3CTComponent%20extends%20React.SFC%3Cany%3E%2C%20TAllProps%20extends%20ComponentProps%3CTComponent%3E%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%09Component%3A%20TComponent%3B%0D%0A%09alias%3CTName%20extends%20string%2C%20TProps%20extends%20Partial%3CComponentProps%3CTComponent%3E%3E%3E(name%3A%20TName%2C%20setProps%3A%20TProps)%3A%0D%0A%09%09HelperSCF%3CTComponent%20%26%20%7B%20%5BP%20in%20TName%5D%3A%20(props%3A%20RestOfProperties%3CTAllProps%2C%20TProps%3E)%20%3D%3E%20JSX.Element%20%7D%2C%20TAllProps%3E%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Define%20the%20aliasFactory%20function%2C%20with%20overlaods%20for%20SCF%20and%20ComponentClass%0D%0Afunction%20aliasFactory%3CTComponent%20extends%20React.SFC%3Cany%3E%3E(Component%3A%20TComponent)%3A%20HelperSCF%3CTComponent%2C%20ComponentProps%3CTComponent%3E%3E%0D%0Afunction%20aliasFactory%3CTComponent%20extends%20React.ComponentClass%3Cany%3E%3E(Component%3A%20TComponent)%3A%20Helper%3CTComponent%2C%20ComponentProps%3CTComponent%3E%3E%0D%0Afunction%20aliasFactory%3CTComponent%20extends%20React.ComponentClass%3Cany%3E%20%7C%20React.SFC%3Cany%3E%3E(Component%3A%20TComponent)%20%7B%0D%0A%09class%20Helper%3CT%20extends%20React.SFC%3Cany%3E%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09public%20constructor(public%20Component%3A%20T)%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%09%09alias%3CTName%20extends%20string%2C%20TProps%20extends%20Partial%3CComponentProps%3CTComponent%3E%3E%3E(name%3A%20TName%2C%20setProps%3A%20TProps)%3A%20any%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09%09(this.Component%20as%20any)%5Bname%5D%20%3D%20(props%3A%20%7B%7D)%20%3D%3E%20null%3B%0D%0A%09%09%09return%20this%3B%0D%0A%09%09%7D%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%09return%20new%20Helper(Component%20as%20any)%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A)

Comment: @Schadenn weird those errors suggest at least your IDE is not on th latest version. I'll try to provide a simplified playground link

Comment: One more question though: Why does typescript allow an object with extra properties if you use Partial<IProps>? For example interface IProps { count: number } will match to an object { count: 1, something: 'hi' } - as long as the extra property is not the first in the object. Is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: @Schadenn Are you sure ? On direct assignment of object literals, excess properties are checked. If you assign a variable that has more properties that is allowed https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20ICounterProps%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20count%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20p%3A%20Partial%3CICounterProps%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20count%3A%2010%2C%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20dadsa%3A%20%22dd%22%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%20let%20o%20%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20count%3A%2010%2C%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20dadsa%3A%20%22dd%22%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Ap%20%3D%20o%20%2F%2F%20this%20is%20allowed%20

Comment: If I use alias('StartAt5', { count: 5, hey: 'how are you' }), there will be no TS error on the setProps parameter. However if I do alias('StartAt5', { hey: 'how are you' }, I get "hey does not exist in type Partial<ComponentProps<ICounter>>". As long as theres one property that's valid, the whole object is valid. Would love to send you an example but I can't find a way to update the typescript version in codesandbox.

Comment: @Schadenn Yup you are right about that one, that is a small wrinkle in how `extends` interacts with extra property checking, we can get around it by making sure that if any excess properties are present, they are of type `never`, not quite perfect but good enough for 99.9% of all possible situations. Edited the definitions of the `alias` methods to have `TProps extends Partial<ComponentProps<TComponent>> & Record<Exclude<keyof TProps, keyof ComponentProps<TComponent>>, never>` a bit of a mouthful but should do the job :)